# sum of two operators is a closed linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a problem with the following question.
Let X and Y be normed spaces. The norm on $X\times Y$ is defined by $\|(x,y)\| = \|x\|+\|y\|$. If $T_1:X \longrightarrow Y$ is a closed linear operator and $T_2 \in L(X,Y)$ (which is the space of bounded linear operators), show that $T_1+T_2$ is a closed linear operator.
I got confused about $T_1$ is on X but $T_2$ is on $X\times Y$, so what is the domain of $T_1+T_2$. Should I use $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ or just $(x,y_1)$ and $(x,y_2)$ to prove the linearity? Also about the closed part, I am considering the closed mapping theorem. Since $T_1$ is closed thus is continous, and $T_2$ is bounded and also continuous. Then $T_1+T_2$ is continuous, thus is closed. Is this right?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The [Closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) requires X and Y to be Banach spaces. So you cannot conclude that $T_1$ is continuous; it remains merely closed.

Answer (score 1):

Neither $T_1$ or $T_2$ are defined on $X\times Y$. $T_1$ is a linear map from some subspace $D(T_1)\subset X$ to $Y$. $T_2$ is a linear map from $X$ to $Y$. I'm not taking $T_1$ to have domain all of $X$, because usually one is looking at operators defined on a Banach space and if a closed operator has as domain a Banach space this operator must already be continuous.

As such the sum $T_1+T_2$ is not defined on all of $X$, but on the subspace $D(T_1)=D(T_1)\cap X$.

First note $D(T_1+T_2)=D(T_1)$. Let $x_n\in D(T_1)$ so that $x_n\to x$ and $(T_1+T_2)(x_n)\to y$. From $T_2$ being continuous you get

$$T_1(x_n)=(T_1+T_2-T_2)(x_n)\to y-T_2(x)$$

It follows $T_1(x_n)$ converges and from the closure of $T_1$ you find $x$ must lie in $D(T_1)$ and $T_1(x)=y-T_2(x)$. Then $(T_1+T_2)(x)=y$. So $T_1+T_2$ is closed.